# Using a printer on a local network with Java

Tags: java, networking, printing, lan

I have project that require a user in LAN to be able to print (physically) a document through network printer attached in same LAN or printer attached at a computer and the computer is connected to same LAN. I write the program in Java.

Any ideas how I could do it?

Comment: Just use the printers available to the user via print menu - whether the printer is local or remote should be transparent to you (Java).

Comment: Apparently, I can't use built in print menu. I need some sort of source code to print a document to network printer, because I plan to integrate it to a mobile agent.

Comment: You had a look at `javax.print`?